# Error When changes spring framework version

Tags: java, spring, scala, sbt

I have used sbt Scala, and my sbt have spring framework
before we have used  org.springframework » spring-beans » 5.2.20.RELEASE
but I need to change use

```
libraryDependencies +=Seq(
  xxx others dependencies
  "org.springframework" % "spring-beans" % "6.0.0",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-core" % "6.0.0"
)
dependencyOverrides += "org.springframework" % "spring-beans" % "6.0.0"
dependencyOverrides += "org.springframework" % "spring-core" % "6.0.0"
```

when I tried to use sbt run I got error like this
cannot access org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils
my question how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Can't reproduce https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/wR6wEps6S7eHZbHo9fJaIQ

Comment: Did you do `sbt clean`?

Comment: Sorry guys after I check java springbootframework need jdk 17... but on my local and my company use java 11